# split file renaming automation

Tags: 14.04, command-line, files, split

After I split my file I want to name them like so. How can I automate this?

```
2048  split -l 500000 10k_edges_sixth_1000.csv
 2049  ls -ltr
 2050  mv xaa 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt1.csv
 2051  mv xab 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt2.csv
 2052  mv xac 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt3.csv
 2053  mv xad 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt4.csv
 2054  mv xae 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt5.csv
 2055  mv xaf 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt6.csv
 2056  mv xag 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt7.csv
 2057  mv xah 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt8.csv
 2058  mv xai 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt9.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

This command should work:

```
split -l 500000 -d --additional-suffix='.csv' 10k_edges_sixth_1000.csv 10k_edges_sixth_1000_pt
```

#### Explanations for flags

- `-l` flag: number of lines per output file.
- `-d` flag: force the use of numeric suffixes.
- `--additional-suffix` flag: adds a user-specified additional suffix to the end of the file name after the numeric suffix (if enabled).

Comment: Newer versions of GNU `split` have an `--additional-suffix`  option that should allow you to add the `.csv` extension without a separate renaming step (by adding `--additional-suffix='.csv'` to the command)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the tip, will edit that in

Comment: FYI not sure if it's available in 14.04 - seems to be in 16.04 (coreutils 8.25) but not in 12.04 (coreutils 8.13)

Comment: @steeldriver I tested it on my 14.04 Ubuntu, it works.